# What is wrong when the car dies after you take off the jumper cables on a 2013 dodge journey?

Tags: battery

What is wrong when the car dies after you take off the jumper cables on a 2013 dodge journey?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! It is likely that the battery is entirely dead, and not holding a charge at all. Pretty easy to have an auto parts store check it for you.

Comment: That or a bad alternator.

Comment: An alternator that is not producing a charge coupled with a dead battery. If the alternator was producing current then the car could run off it even with a dead battery. If the battery had even a meager charge the engine could run off it even if the alternator was not producing current. Both have to be incapable of supply spark to the engine if the engine dies immediately after removing the jumper cables. Whether the battery can be recharged (and hold a charge) is yet to be seen.